# Artifactory + Custom Gradle Plugin Programmatically (2022)

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a custom gradle plugin (100% java) which will automatically configure Artifactory, avoiding the need of the following DSL:

```
artifactory {
contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
publish {
    repository {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        repoKey = 'android-dev'
        username = "${artifactory_user}"
        password = "${artifactory_password}"
        maven = true

    }
}
resolve {
    repository {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        repoKey = 'android-dev-distributions'
        username = "${artifactory_user}"
        password = "${artifactory_password}"
        maven = true

    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to re-create @agrosner own solution (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25669431/1880280) but I'm missing "ArtifactoryAction". I can't find it anywhere.

The nonworking version posted by @agrosner is the following code:

```
// Set up plugins so we never need to add them to a build.gradle
    project.getPlugins().apply(MAVEN);
    project.getPlugins().apply(ARTIFACTORY);
    project.setGroup(GROUP);

    // Add Artifactory repo to the repositories
    project.getRepositories().maven(new ArtifactoryAction(contextUrl + ARTIFACTORY_REPO_ENDPOINT, user, pass));

    // We will define the plugin convention here so all of our libraries do not need to
    // declare the artifactory closure manually
    ArtifactoryPluginConvention pluginConvention =
            ArtifactoryPluginUtil.getArtifactoryConvention(project);
    pluginConvention.setContextUrl(contextUrl);

    PublisherConfig publisherConfig = new PublisherConfig(pluginConvention);
    publisherConfig.setContextUrl(contextUrl);
    pluginConvention.setPublisherConfig(publisherConfig);

    // Use reflection to access private field
    PublisherConfig.Repository repository = null;

    Field[] fields = PublisherConfig.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("repository")) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                repository = (PublisherConfig.Repository) field.get(publisherConfig);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    if(repository != null) {
        repository.setPassword(pass);
        repository.setUsername(user);
        repository.setRepoKey(PUBLISHER_REPO_KEY);
        repository.setMavenCompatible(true);
    }

    GradleArtifactoryClientConfigUpdater.update(pluginConvention.getClientConfig(), project.getRootProject());
```

Can anyone help with an updated 100% java version of this?

Additionally, how would be for the following DSL?

```
artifactory {
publish {
    repository {
        repoKey =  'default-gradle-dev-local' // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
        username = "${artifactory_user}" // The publisher user name
        password = "${artifactory_password}" // The publisher password
        maven       = true
    }
    defaults {
        publications('mavenJava')
        publishArtifacts = true
        publishPom = true
    }
}}
```

Thanks in advance

César

ps. The DSL version that was published at @agrosner question thread is not useful for me. I need a Java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question related to `ArtifactoryAction`: this is neither Gradle API nor Artifactory plugin related api, but most probably a custom class that the response author has implemented himself, as a shortcut to declare his custom Artifactory maven repo.

See [this API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#maven-org.gradle.api.Action-), used to declare maven repositories :

```
MavenArtifactRepository maven​(Action<? super MavenArtifactRepository> action)
```

So you can use:

```
project.getRepositories().maven( mavenArtifactRepository -> {
     mavenArtifactRepository.setUrl(contextUrl + MAVEN_PUBLIC_REPO);
     mavenArtifactRepository.getCredentials().setUsername("user");
     mavenArtifactRepository.getCredentials().setPassword("password");
});
```

or wrap the action code into a custom implementation of `Action<? super MavenArtifactRepository>` :

```
project.getRepositories().maven( new ArtifactoryAction(contextUrl + MAVEN_PUBLIC_REPO, "user", "password")        );

[...]
// custom action class, defined somewhere else
class ArtifactoryAction implements Action<MavenArtifactRepository> {
    private final String url, userName, password;

    ArtifactoryAction(String url, String userName, String password) {
        this.url = url; this.userName = userName; this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(MavenArtifactRepository target) {
        target.setUrl(url);
        target.getCredentials().setUsername(userName);
        target.getCredentials().setPassword(password);
    }
}
```

For the other question with java translation of the `artifactory { }` DSL : see full example below with some inline comments. ( not tested but translated from my kotlin implementation which works fine)

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.plugins.MavenPublishPlugin;
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin;
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPluginUtil;
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ArtifactoryPluginConvention;
import org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.PublisherConfig;

public class CustomArtifactoryPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private static String MAVEN_PUBLIC_REPO = "/maven-public";
    private String contextUrl = "MY_CUSTOM_REPO_BASE_URL";

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {

        // Base gradle publishing plugin
        //  - maven plugin for pulishing java artefacts
        //  - ivy plugin if for publishing other type of artefacts: rpms, archives, ..
        project.getPluginManager().apply(MavenPublishPlugin.class);
        // project.getPluginManager().apply(IvyPublishPlugin.class);

        // Apply the Artifactory plugin
        project.getPluginManager().apply(ArtifactoryPlugin.class);

        // Add Artifactory repo to the repositories
        project.getRepositories().maven(new ArtifactoryAction(contextUrl + MAVEN_PUBLIC_REPO, "user", "password"));

        // Configure artifactory plugin - using 'withPlugin' ensures that plugin has already been applied
        project.getPluginManager().withPlugin("com.jfrog.artifactory", appliedPlugin -> {
            // artifactory {
            ArtifactoryPluginConvention pluginConvention = ArtifactoryPluginUtil.getArtifactoryConvention(project);
            //    contextUrl = "${contextUrl}"
            pluginConvention.setContextUrl(contextUrl);
            //    publish {
            PublisherConfig publisherConfig = new PublisherConfig(pluginConvention);
            pluginConvention.setPublisherConfig(publisherConfig);
            //      repository {
            pluginConvention.getPublisherConfig().repository(repository -> {
                //      repoKey =  'default-gradle-dev-local'  ...
                repository.setRepoKey("default-gradle-dev-local"); // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
                repository.setUsername("${artifactory_user}"); // The publisher user name
                repository.setPassword("${artifactory_password}"); // The publisher password
                repository.setMavenCompatible(true);
            });
            //      defaults {
            pluginConvention.getPublisherConfig().defaults(artifactoryTask -> {
                //      publications('mavenJava')
                artifactoryTask.publications("mavenJava");
                artifactoryTask.setPublishArtifacts("true");
                artifactoryTask.setPublishPom("true");
            });

        });
    }

}
```

*EDIT*  for the publication configuration, you can do as follows:

```
        // create maven publication
        project.getExtensions().configure(PublishingExtension.class, publishingExtension -> {
            publishingExtension.publications(publications -> {
                publications.create("mavenPublication", MavenPublication.class, mavenPublication -> {
                    mavenPublication.setVersion("1.0.0");
                    mavenPublication.setGroupId("groupId");
                    mavenPublication.from(project.getComponents().findByName("java"));
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you M.Ricciuti. Now, the code is working in terms of connecting to Artifactory and pushing the "build info", but it is not pushing the jar neither pom as it does when using the DSL. 

In the DSL I have this that would also like to move to the custom plugin:

 publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

What can I be missing?

Comment: M.Ricciuti: BTW: In the build.gradle I have to import the Artifactory Plugin, if not It neither pushes the "build info". This way:

plugins {
    id 'org.gegolabs.base' version '0.0.1-105'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.26.1"
}
NOTE: "org.gegolabs.base" is the plugin I'm developing

Comment: Oops! I found my problem. I was executing your code inside "        project.getGradle().projectsEvaluated(g -> { <<CODE HERE>>}". I placed it outside and worked. Thank you very much. Still... I'm missing the java code for the following part, please advise:

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

        }
    }
}

Comment: @gego see edited answer for publication configuration

Comment: Hmm. If `artifactoryTask.publications("mavenJava")` fails with _Extension of type 'PublishingExtension' does not exist_, even thouh the maven-publish plugin is applied, what might be the problem? I have copied your example line by line.

Comment: (My) problem solved. This was applied in a multi-module build, and it appears that `publisherConfig.defaults` actually contain projects that have _not_ applied any of the two relevant plugins (artifactory and maven-publish).